# JPA TypedQuery doesn't return results with given condition

Tags: java, database, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have the following models:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "product")
    public class Product implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "product_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_id_seq", sequenceName = "product_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
        private List<ProductContent> productContent;

        @Column(name = "expired_at", nullable = false)
        @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date expiredAt;

        @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
        @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date createdAt;
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "product_content")
    public class ProductContent {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "product_content_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_content_id_seq", sequenceName = "product_content_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "content", columnDefinition="TEXT", nullable = false)
        private String content;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        private Product product;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "supported_locale_id")
        private SupportedLocale locale;
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "supported_locale")
    public class SupportedLocale {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "supported_locale_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "supported_locale_id_seq", sequenceName = "supported_locale_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "language_name", nullable = false)
        private String languageName;

        @Column(name = "language_tag", nullable = false)
        private String languageTag;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "locale")
        private List<ProductContent> productContent;
```

I want to fetch all products in english language. I'm using following typed query:

```
List<Product> products = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN p.productContent pc JOIN pc.locale l WHERE l.languageName=:languageName", Product.class)
                .setParameter("languageName", "English")
                .getResultList();
```

It returns me list of products not limited to English language(there are spanish productContent for example). I also tried to use the generated SQL query directly on database (Postgres) and it works fine (It returns only products with english language). How could I solve it?

Comment: How does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: SELECT t1.id, t1.created_at, t1.expired_at FROM product_content t0, supported_locale t2, product t1 WHERE ((t2.language_name = ?) AND ((t0.product_id = t1.id) AND (t2.id = t0.supported_locale_id)))
 bind => [English]

Comment: Ah now I understand your question. You cannot limit the content of the List productContent with a query on Product

Comment: What would be the right approach then to achieve my condition?

Comment: You should query for ProductContent and then use get the Product from there